# Area of the graph $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ over the ring $r^2 <(x^2+y^2)<4$ with $0<r<2$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

Could someone please help me calculate the surface area of the graph $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ over the ring $r^2 <(x^2+y^2)<4$ with $0<r<2$

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you must show what you did about it. Otherwise, MSE people are reluctant to answer. As a new user, you have to have that condition in mind for the future. Welcome to MSE.

Comment: What have you tried? :D